# Opening a pdf file

Tags: html, pdf, anchor

I have a link with my help file in pdf. To open the
pdf file i use the

```
<a href="myhelp.pdf" target="PDF" rel="help">help</a>
```

The pdf file is opened to a new window, however the path
is shown in the title bar.

Do you guys know how to change the title bar? In 
window.open the title bar can be changed. 
I tried to use window.open for the onClick() but because
my Help is a label and not a button, I have to use the
link anchor and it still shows the path in the title bar.

Do you have any idea for a workaround?

Im thinking of putting the pdf in a dialog, do you have suggestions on how to go about it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your goal to completely hide the real path to the file so someone can't share the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever displays the PDF, such as the Acrobat Reader plugin, will set the browser's title-bar, and you can only change it from the PDF, using a PDF editor like Adobe Creator.

One trick could be to open a new window, and inside it, open the PDF in an iframe...

Comment: hey thanks! Tried it and can change the title already.. but the iFrame, how can it take the size of the browser its embedded in? Because when the browser is maximized, the iframe size remains :9

Comment: style it with CSS width: and height: at 100%. If that doesn't work (height doesn't work in Chrome, for example), detect the page height in javascript and set the iframe height there... like <iframe id="if" onload="document.getElementById('if').height=window.innerHeight"